# Grid view with columns from multiple tables but unable to display image in the gridview

Tags: gridview, yii, yii-extensions

cant display image in the gridview wherein this  grid view with columns from multiple tables  .. following is what i have done am using EImageColumn..... i dont no where am i wrong ...... can any one please guide me

gridview in model2

```
  tbl2 columns
 array('header'=>'Pimg', 'value'=>array(
        'class'=>'EImageColumn',
        'name' => 'pimg',   //name of column from tbl1 and model1
        'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 100px;'),

        )), 
   tbl3 columns
```

can any one please guide me

if i place the above code i get this error

```
**call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members**
```

Comment: try to add `'type'=>'html',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class`,`name` and `htmlOptions` should not be in the `value` array, just like in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image-column/

```
array(
    'header'=>'Pimg', 
    'class'=>'EImageColumn',
    'name' => 'm1.pimg', //assuming the relation to model1 in model2 is named m1
    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 100px;'),
    'value'=>'...',// if required
),
```

Comment: pimg is in model1(parent)and i wanna display it in a gridview which is in model2 (child) i do have relations as well it extracts the text data from model2 in model1 but not the image from model2 in model1 .... i get Property "Model1.pimg" is not defined. as exception when i placed your code .... and thats true bcoz its model2 property

Comment: Property "model2.m1.pimg" is not defined its trowing

Comment: Replace m1 with what the relation of model1 in model2 is named.

Comment: i refered m1 as model2 its my mistake i worte Property "model2.model1relationname.pimg" is not defined its trowing

Comment: wrked :) in I've changed renderDataCellContent function, to support names with relations, like 'name'=>'Post.Author'

//$image = CHtml::image($this->pathPrefix . $data->{$this->name} . $this->pathSuffix,
        $image = CHtml::image($this->pathPrefix . CHtml::value($data,$this->name) . $this->pathSuffix,